# Gerar backup do banco de dados

Tags: sql-server, backup

Em meu projeto, tenho um banco de dados que tem bastante registro. Então eu queria que o SQL Server fizesse um *backup* por dia ou por semana. Mas acho que o por dia é melhor.

Mas como posso fazer esse *script* pra que fique programado no SQL Server e ele faça o *backup* programado, sem precisar de ninguém forçando ele a fazer?

A versão que uso do SQL Server é a 2012.

Comment: Cara, começa um código e quando surgirem as dúvidas nós ajudamos...
Se bem que eu acho que tem como muda alguma configuração do SQL Server para fazer isso.

Comment: Então a questão é que não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso. :(. Já até pesquisei, mas não achei nada de tão relevante. Ou então eu não procurei direito.

Comment: Eu acho que a pergunta é válida. É curta, objetiva, não depende de opinião, não requer uma resposta ampla demais e é algo que muitos desenvolvedores não sabem como fazer. Além do +1 vai uma favoritada. P.S.: eu não sou o Renan que respondeu.

Comment: Exatamente. Tem muitos que não sabem fazer, inclusive eu, e muito menos onde começar a pesquisa. E muito obrigado pela favoritada !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se você deseja apenas um script ***Transact-SQL*** para fazer o *backup*, você pode usar algo como:

```
USE SeuBanco;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE SeuBanco
TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\SeuBanco.Bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Backup Full do SeuBanco';
GO
```

A sintaxe básica é:

```
BACKUP DATABASE nomeDoBanco 
TO lugarOndeSeraGravado
```

Veja maiores detalhes sobre a sintaxe para criação do *script* [**aqui**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx) e se você deseja gerar *backups* de diferencial a partir de um *backup full* pode usar a cláusula [**DIFFERENTIAL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188248.aspx).

Mas é recomendável você programar um *job* para automatizar isso usando o ***SQL Server Agent***.

Clique com o botão direito em ***Jobs*** e em seguida em ***New Job***...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na guia *General*, em *Name*, escreva o nome que achar conveniente para seu *job*.

Na guia *Steps*, clique no botão *New* para você criar os passos do seu *job*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Informe um nome para o passo, tipo do *backup*, o *script* e configure o agendamento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para maiores detalhes, de uma olhada [**aqui**](http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-agendamento-de-backup-no-sql-server-r2/24640).